# How to wrap second child around a first child using Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

We're trying to get the following result using Flexbox, but cannot seem to get the line on the right to wrap around **Mr. Bond**:

Desired output:

[image]

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-child-1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.flex-child-2 {}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-child-1">Mr. Bond</div>
  <div class="flex-child-2">We would like for this text to continue on your right hand side on the same line after your name, then continue to a new line under your name and continue the pattern until all the text is done.</div>
</div>
```

Any idea how to accomplish the desired result using Flexbox layout?

[Here is the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/52kr0q71/)

Comment: Not possible with flexbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **cannot** do this using flexbox or CSS grid (it's simply impossible). You have two possibilies.

Either using float:

```css
.flex-child-1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-child-1">Mr. Bond</div>
  <div class="flex-child-2">We would like for this text to continue on your right hand side on the same line after your name, then continue to a new line under your name and continue the pattern until all the text is done.</div>
</div>
```

Or inline elements like stated in the other answer.

```css
.flex-child-1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-right:5px;
}
.flex-child-1,
.flex-child-2 {
  display:inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-child-1">Mr. Bond</div>
  <div class="flex-child-2">We would like for this text to continue on your right hand side on the same line after your name, then continue to a new line under your name and continue the pattern until all the text is done.</div>
</div>
```

---

Or you *hack* it with your flexbox structure but it doesn't mean you can do it with flexbox

```css
.flex-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.flex-child-1 {
  font-weight: bold;
  width:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
}

.flex-child-2 {
  text-indent:80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-child-1">Mr. Bond</div>
  <div class="flex-child-2">We would like for this text to continue on your right hand side on the same line after your name, then continue to a new line under your name and continue the pattern until all the text is done.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

If not using CSS is okay, you can use this solution utilizing `<b>` tags. It makes use of [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements).

```html
<div>
  <p><b>Mr. Bond</b> We would like for this text to continue on your right hand side on the same line after your name, then continue to a new line under your name and continue the pattern until all the text is done.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: We know how to do it using inline HTML elements, but we're trying to accomplish this using Flexbox

Comment: As far as I know, you aren't able to achieve such result using Flexbox. Flexbox won't be able to fluidly wrap the words in your paragraph.

Comment: I agree, I don't think this can be achieved using flexbox